# lightning:outputField get value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Is it possible to get the value of a "lightning: outputField" to pass it to the controller? I used a lightning:recordViewForm to display record's values.

```
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="Contact">      
    <lightning:card title="Contact Details">          
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">                        
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="FirstName" />    
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="LastName" />    
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="MobilePhone" />    
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="AccountId" />    
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Department" />    
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Birthdate" />    
                </div>
            </div>
        </p>
    </lightning:card>        
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```

For example how can i get the value of mobilephone field?

Answer (score 2):

No, you would need a [force:recordData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData) component instead. Since both are built on LDS (Lightning Data Service), you can get the data "for free" (e.g. no extra round-trip to the server) by using force:recordData.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have actually done this.

Answer (score 0):

@sfdcfox I have actually done this on inputfield, and if irc, you can do on output as well. I cannot test because salesforce is down for me including my sandbox.

```
<lightning:inputField fieldName="VIP_Request_Type__c" required="true" onchange="{!c.validate}" value="{!v.vip}"/>
```

in my controller, I called the cmp.get("v.vip") to get the value. I really dislike recorddata component and much prefer

I think it can be tricky though to make sure the component is rendered with a value before it is sent to the controller otherwise you may get a null value.

Comment: (a) this won't work with outputField at all. You can assign the attributes value and onchange, but they do nothing. (b) even with inputField, the user would need to modify the field's value before it will fire an onchange. As much as one might dislike force:recordData, it's the only solution outside of writing Apex code. Also, FYI, the various lightning:*form elements internally use force:recordData as well.

Comment: can't you use inputfield and then make it read only?

Comment: No. The value won't be updated until a change occurs (triggering an aura:valueChange), and making it read-only would eliminate that possibility. I do like your ideas, they're clever, but unfortunately it just doesn't work that way. I even tried using `aura:handler name="change"` to see if I could get a value change event on the attribute itself, still nothing.